# Mongoose schema - how to apply to create defined indices?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, indexing, schema

I have an older application that uses Mongoose (mongoose 5.13.14 I can't use v6 because the app is a traditional js file not a module). I have modified the application and now want to start over with a fresh database.

The main problem I am facing is that I can use the existing Mongoose schemas in my application but the defined indices in that schema are not applied.

How can I make Mongoose force to apply that schema and create the necessary indices?

For example there is the following index defined for the url field:

```
var VersionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: { unique: true }
    }
    ...
}
VersionSchema.set('autoIndex', true); // just to make sure

module.exports = mongoose.model('version', VersionSchema);
```

In the main application I use it for example this way ( I left out some require statements that reference the schema).

```
const result = await models.version.countDocuments({"url": someUrl});
```

Why are the indices not created? Even if I drop the "versions" db and let it recreate by mongoose the indices are not created.

Edit: I have explicitly set `autoIndex: true` on both the connection and the schema.

Comment: Do you have the `autoIndex` option set to false anywhere in your connection or schema?

Comment: I have set `autoIndex: true` on both the connection and the schema.